# $\omega$ satisfies $a \omega^3 + b \omega^2 + c \omega + d = 0$, Prove that $ |\omega| \leq \max( \frac{b}{a}, \frac{c}{b}, \frac{d}{c})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

If $\omega$ is a complex number that satisfies $a \omega^3 + b \omega^2 + c \omega + d = 0$, **where $a,b,c,d$ are positive real numbers**, prove that $|\omega| \leq \max( \frac{b}{a}, \frac{c}{b}, \frac{d}{c})$

This just seems so simple and elegant yet I can't wrap my head around. Was trying to tackle from vieta's formula but nothing fruitful yet.

Another idea was to make the polynomial $\omega^3 + \frac{b}{a} \omega^2 + \frac{c}{b} \omega + \frac{d}{c} = 0$, and prove some contradiction if $\omega > \max( \frac{b}{a}, \frac{c}{b}, \frac{d}{c})$. It might be closer to what we want.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2682490.

Comment: The reference @Martin R gave you is interesting by the answer of Achille Hui showing that this issue is a particular case of Kakeya's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $r=\max( \frac{b}{a}, \frac{c}{b}, \frac{d}{c})$. To simplify the problem, use the substitution $\omega =rz$,
$$
ar^3z^3+br^2z^2+crz+d=0,\\
az^3+\frac{b}{r} z^2+ \frac{c}{r^2} z+\frac{d}{r^3}=0,\\
z^3+B z^2+ C z+D=0, D\leq C\le B\le 1.
$$
Now, consider 
$$
f(z)=(1-z)(z^3+B z^2+ C z+D)+z^4=(1-B)z^3+(B-C)z^2+(C-D)z+D.
$$
For $|z|=1$, $f(z)\leq |1-B|+|B-C|+|C-D|+D=1$, so $|z^3f(1/z)|\leq 1\times 1=1$.

By maximum modulus principle, $|z^3f(1/z)|\le 1$ for all $|z|\le 1$. That means for $|z|>1$, $|f(z)/z^3|\le 1$, $|f(z)|\le |z|^3$ Therefore,
$$
|(1-z)(z^3+B z^2+ C z+D)|=|f(z)-z^4|\ge -|f(z)|+|z|^4\\
\ge |z|^4-|z^3|=|z|^3(1-|z|)>0 
$$ 
for $|z|>1$, so for $(1-z)(z^3+B z^2+ C z+D)=0$, $|z|\leq 1$. As a result,
$$
|\omega|\le |r||z|\le r.
$$
For more information, see [this document.](https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/pubs/GardnerGovilF.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that takes advantage of the simplified context given by the four first lines of the answer by @Jethro, switching from there to a simple geometrical proof.

Let us assume indeed that

$$z^3+B z^2+ C z+D=0, \ \ \ D\leq C\le B\le 1 \ \tag{1}$$

where we have to show that $|z| \leq 1$.

Let us consider the case of a complex root

$$z:=\rho e^{i \theta}\tag{2}$$

(we can assume that $0<\theta<\pi$ possibly up to the consideration of the complex conjugate root).

Let us show that necessarily $\rho\leq 1$.

Assume on the contrary that $\rho>1$, in order to obtain a contradiction.

Consider for that the quadrilateral with vertices

$$P:=0, \ \ Q:=D, \ \ R:=D+Cz, \ \ S:=D+Cz+Bz^2$$

[image]

whose sidelengths $D,Cr,B\rho^2,\rho^3$ are ranked in the following order (as a consequence of (1) and the fact that $r>1$):

$$D < Cr < B\rho^2 < \rho^3$$

i.e., $PQRS$ is a quadrilateral with equal opposite angles $a=\pi-\alpha$ (in vertices $Q$ and $S$)  and increasing sidelengths. But this is impossible (See the answer to my recent question [How to prove that no quadrilateral exist with three equal angles and increasing sidelengths](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3466494)).

Remark : a different computation shows that one gets as well a contradiction for a **real** root $z=-\rho$ with $\rho>1$.