# How to prove that no quadrilateral exist with three equal angles and increasing sidelengths

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

Working on an alternative solution to this recent question [$\omega$ satisfies $a \omega^3 + b \omega^2 + c \omega + d = 0$, Prove that $ |\omega| \leq \max( \frac{b}{a}, \frac{c}{b}, \frac{d}{c})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3465542), I was brought to another question : how to prove that it is impossible for a quadrilateral $PQRS$ (see figure below) to have 3 equal angles $$a=\widehat{PQR}=\widehat{QRS}=\widehat{RSP}\tag{1}$$ and increasing sidelengths

$$0<PQ<QR<RS<SP\tag{2}$$

[image]

*Fig. 1 : An obviously inexact figure (for the very fact that it is impossible to have such a quadrilateral !).*

I have attempted to work in different directions, Bretschneider's formula, spirals, etc... without any result.

Remark : The connection with the cited problem or more exactly the formulation given in the fourth line of the accepted solution by @Jethro is as follows. Points $P,Q,R,S$ correspond resp. to complex numbers $D,D+Cz,D+Cz+Bz^2,0$ where $z=re^{i\theta}$ is a complex root of equation $D+Cz+Bz^2+z^3=0$ with common angle $a=\pi-\alpha$ and lengthes $PQ=D,QR=Cr,RS=Br^2,SP=r^3$. We have to prove that $r \leq 1$. Therefore, I have assumed that $r>1$, which, taking into account that $D \leq C \leq B$, yields relationship (2), aiming a contradiction.

Comment: [Omar Khayyam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omar_Khayyam) and [Giovanni Saccheri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Girolamo_Saccheri) proved many results similar to the one you want to prove, perhaps even including that one ... I will do some searching

Comment: @Zubin Mukerjee Thanks, I will be waiting...

Comment: Not a complete answer yet, just my thoughts so far, so I will comment here:$$\,$$Suppose for contradiction that there is such a quadrilateral.$$\,$$ **Case 1:** $$0 < a < \pi/2$$ **Case 2**: $$a = \pi/2$$ **Case 3**: $$\pi/2 < a < 2\pi/3$$ **Case 4**: $$2\pi/3 < a$$

Clearly Case 2 is just a square, so this doesn't work. Case 4 violates angle sum of a quadrilateral. For Case 1: Let $A$ be the intersection of $\overleftrightarrow{QP}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{RS}$. Let $B$ be the intersection of $\overleftrightarrow{SP}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{RQ}$. Then $$\triangle ARQ \sim \triangle BSR$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Quadrilateral with 3 equal angles of a]

As shown in the diagram above, join $Q$ to $S$. Also, let $\angle SQP = d$, so $\angle SQR = a - d$, plus let $\angle QSR = f$, so $\angle QSP = a - f$.

As shown & explained in [Relationship of side lengths and angles of a triangle](https://www.mathopenref.com/trianglesideangle.html), plus as mentioned in the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466494/how-to-prove-that-no-quadrilateral-exist-with-three-equal-angles-and-increasing/3466515#comment7126502_3466515) about [Euclid's I.18](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI18.html), the angle opposite the greater side length is greater. Thus, with $\triangle QSR$, since $SR \gt QR$, you have

$$\angle SQR \gt \angle QSR \implies a - d \gt f \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Next, with $\triangle QSP$, since $SP \gt PQ$, you have

$$\angle SQP \gt \angle QSP \implies d \gt a - f \implies - a + d \gt -f \implies a - d \lt f \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

However, this contradicts \eqref{eq1A} (also, adding $a - d \gt f$ to $d \gt a - f$ gives $a \gt a$ for another way to see this doesn't work). This means the stated conditions of the relationships of the side lengths, i.e., $PQ \lt QR \lt RS \lt SP$, cannot be correct. Note, also, this proof doesn't even need, or use, that $\angle QRS = a$ or $RS \gt SP$.

Comment: Here you are using [Euclid's I.18](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI18.html)? "In any triangle the angle opposite the greater side is greater."

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee You are correct. I just provided a link to a Web page which also explains this, and will add your link as well.

Comment: Is there a typo on $(1)$? Both read $\angle QSR$ .. maybe should be this? $$\angle SQR > \angle QSR$$

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Thanks, it was a typo. I've now fixed it.

Comment: OK, looks good now. Because this only uses Euclid's I.18, and you never used the parallel postulate, I think you have proved that such a quadrilateral cannot exist in Euclidean geometry, nor in hyperbolic geometry ... very nice, +1 :)

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Thanks for the compliment. To help make it easier to visualize, I've just added a rough diagram. Note I was only interested in proving this for Euclidean geometry, so if it also works in hyperbolic geometry, that is a definite bonus.

Comment: Because, as you mention, your proof did not use/need the fact that the 3rd "middle" angle was equal to $a$, I am wondering if there is a name for such quadrilaterals that have just one pair of opposite angles equal ... but one [such quadrilateral](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qvte5q4xq3) that I drew does not seem to look at all like  the special quadrilaterals that I know the names of, like a **kite** or a **rhombus** or a **parallelogram** ... maybe there is no special name for this group? unlucky

Comment: If a quadrilateral has two opposite interior angles that are equal, and it is [cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral), then it must be a [**right kite**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_kite) ...

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Actually, as your linked Wikipedia article says, "A convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ is cyclic if and only if its opposite angles are supplementary ...". The opposite angles don't need to be equal, with this only occurring if they are both right angles. Instead, I don't think there's any special name for this type of quadrilateral. The Web page at [Identifying the Seven Quadrilaterals](https://www.dummies.com/education/math/geometry/identifying-the-seven-quadrilaterals/) lists these as being kite, parallelogram, trapezoid, isosceles trapezoid, rhombus, rectangle & square.

Comment: Yes, I mean to say that all cyclic quadrilaterals with one pair of opposite interior angles equal are "right kites"... I also could not find a name for quadrilaterals with just the "one pair of opposite angles equal" requirement :( maybe they are not special enough to be named?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Sorry, I misread what you wrote in your earlier comment. I agree quadrilaterals with the condition of just $2$ opposite angles being equal are likely not used enough, and are not considered special enough, to have any specific (at least any common) name assigned to them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, John, it is interesting to know that in fact, the existence or two **opposite** equal angles suffices (albeit the existence of two **consecutive** equal angles would not lead to a contradiction).

Answer (score 6):

Using an aspect of the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem) that tells us $Q$ and $S$ must lie on congruent circular arcs with common chord $\overline{PR}$, we have this diagrammatic proof:

[image]

Like [@JohnOmielan's proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3466515/409), this one doesn't use any information about $\angle R$. *Unlike* @John's proof, this one is only valid in Euclidean geometry (where IAT holds). It's worth noting that both proofs are valid even for self-intersecting $\square PQRS$ with $Q$ and $S$ on the same side of $\overline{PR}$.

---

Regarding a hyperbolic counterpart: The locus of a point that makes a constant angle with two other points is a simple curve. According to [this answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/86601), the locus in the Klein model is actually a circle. So, embedding my diagram in the Klein disk with $M$ at the origin *almost* works. One would still need to show that smaller arcs (in the model) correspond to smaller lengths (in the geometry); presumably, the argument would effectively duplicate @John's logic, so this diagrammatic approach merely adds unnecessary complication.

Comment: A simple proof indeed !